# Javascript higher order function, calling a function with n parameters

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am trying to learn about currying. And maybe that isn't the way to do this, so please I am open to any elegant and functioning answer.

Basically, I have some code that I reuse often, making a function run on page load and that works across browsers:

```
const xOnLoadify = (fn) => {
  if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('onload', fn); }
  else if (window.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener('load', fn, false); }
  else { document.addEventListener('load', fn, false); }
};
```

However, using this xOnLoadify function, I can only call it with default parameters. How can I modify this, so that I can pass any number of arguments to any fn function?

I have tried something like:

```
const xOnLoadify = () => (fn) => {
  if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('onload', fn); }
  else if (window.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener('load', fn, false); }
  else { document.addEventListener('load', fn, false); }
};
```

But I don't know how to get the arguments into fn, without calling fn immediately, `fn(args);`

Ideally, the answer would make it so that I could use xOnLoadify with any number of arguments formatted for the fn passed in.

Ex;

```
    function myNiftyFunction(arg1='default1', arg2='default2', arg3='default3') {
      // don't want the args to be these defaults
      console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
```

Then something like, `xOnLoadify(myNiftyFunction)(arg1,arg2,arg3);`

This is both a particular question and a general theoretical question. I am going to use the answer, but would also like to understand so that I can extend my knowledge and use this concept in the future.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a spread parameter through currying and then bind the function:

```
const xOnLoadify = (fn) => (...args) => {
  fn = fn.bind(this, ...args); // bind arguments to the function
  if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('onload', fn); }
  else if (window.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener('load', fn, false); }
  else { document.addEventListener('load', fn, false); }
};
```

Then you can call it as:

```
xOnLoadify(myNiftyFunction)(arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work.... when I call `xOnLoadify(myNiftyFunction)();` to let the default parameters come in - arg1 is overwritten with the window event OR if I call it as `xOnLoadify(myNiftyFunction)(myArg);` arg2 is overwritten with the window event. It works for non-default, which is a great start :)

Comment: @will then pass `e => fn()` instead of `fn`

Answer (score 0):

What I think your after is `bind`,..

Here is a simple example..

```js
function callthis(a,b,c) {
  console.log(`a=${a}, b=${b}, c=${c}`);
}

function test(fn, ...args) {
  const fncall = fn.bind(null, ...args);
  fncall();
}

test(callthis, 1, 2, 3);
```